# Rename all files in subdirecories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files, rename

I am having a problem writing a script for mass renaming of files in subdirectories.

I have a folder with multiple subfolders, and those subfolders have multiple files that I need to rename.

This is the where I got so far:

```
for file in $(find -name "*.report")
do
  mv "$file" "LPP_${file/LP_/}"
done
```

So as you can see, I need to replace the 'LP_' string in the filename with the 'LPP_'.

This is not working because of the path to the file - the strings retrieved from the find command are only file names, and don't include the path. To include the path, I am trying something like this:

```
for file in $(find -name "*.report")
do
  echo "$file" 
  echo "${RELPATH/\$\//}/${file/LP_/LPP_}"
done
```

But the RELPATH variable is prefixing a '/' character, so the mv command is complaining that it cannot move the file to /./subfolder1/LPP_filename.report

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, is there a better way of doing it, and explain why is there an extra '/' character in te RELPATH variable and how to remove it?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Just a heads-up: that *for* loop won't work in files/folders with names that contain spaces! You should use something like what *steeldriver* suggests in his answer.

Comment: well, I might consider to start using python for stuff like this, but can you first point me to some materials on how to set it up?
I can use windows cmd, anything. I am looking for something that I will use in future, i thought git bash is good enough to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your issue (`find` *should* return the full path), however I suggest a different approach, perhaps something like

```
find -name '*.report' -execdir bash -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0/LP_/LPP_}"' {} \;
```

By passing the `find` result `{}` as a shell positional parameter `$0` to a subordinate `bash -c` command, we can work around the fact that we can't do `mv {} ${{}/LP_/LPP_}` directly. The use of `-execdir` instead of the more common `-exec` ensures that the substitution happens only on the filename portion, in case any of the paths happens to contain the string `LP_`

The `echo` is just so you can try it out and check that the renaming looks correct - you will need to remove it to allow actual renaming.

Comment: When I run this in bash, it says:
find: invalid predicate `-execdir'
when I run only find command, it can't find any file, and there are files in there, in subdirectories. I am using git bash installed on my windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the find command, it must have been too late for me to think properly, don't know how I missed it.
Here is the code with which I managed to pull it off:
`for file in $(find -name "*.report")
do
  mv "$file" "${file/LP_/LPP_}"
done`
If you could provide some more details around your answer, and maybe include this approach in the answer as well and I will then mark your answer as the best answer. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @sskular there are 2 issues with the code in your comment above: (1) it will break if any of the paths contains a space (word splitting); and (2) it will try to rename the *first* instance of `LP_` anywhere in the path so will also break if any of the subdirectory names happens to include the string `LP_`. If it works for your case that's fine - but it's not a robust solution in general.